# Why does mapshot in R (mapview package) not save the addWebGLHeatmap (leaflet extras) layer?

Tags: r, leaflet, heatmap

Please help me with the following.

I am making a heatmap using leaflet and addWebGLHeatmap. This works fine, until I try and save the plot as PNG using webshot. See the code below:

```
m <- map %>% 
  addWebGLHeatmap(data = dataset, lng=~lon, lat=~lat, size = 800, 
  opacity = 0.6, intensity = 1) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = shapefile, weight = 2, color = "black", fillOpacity = 0)

mapshot(m, file = "testRplot.png")
```

What it shows in plotviewer:
[Plot in viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvdrV.jpg)

What it shows after saving:
[Plot after saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQiqg.jpg)

Hope anyone is able to help.

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Yes, sorry. should have started with that.

 testframe <- data.frame(
  lat = rnorm(500, mean = 50, sd = 0.1),
  lon = rnorm(500, mean = 4, sd = 0.05))

testmap <- leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.Terrain") %>% 
  setView(map, lng = 4.0,lat = 50.0 ,zoom = 9)

save <- testmap %>%
  addWebGLHeatmap(data = testframe, lng=~lon, lat=~lat, size = 4000, opacity = 0.60, intensity = 0.25)

mapshot(save, file = "heatmap.png")

Comment: library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(mapview)
library(dplyr)

Comment: This also fails if we first save to html with `saveWidget` (which still has the webgl layer) and then try to convert to png with `webshot` (which looses the webgl layer - and I have no idea why). I'd recommend opening an issue at https://github.com/wch/webshot with the example code from your comment above as it seems likely that this is due to the webgl not being handled by webshot.

Comment: Thanks, I just did. Hope someone can fix it.