# Saving a WebGLHeatmap from Leaflet.extras to a png in R

Tags: r, leaflet, webgl

I'm working on a project in which I would like create and save WebGLHeatmap images from the leaflet.extras in an automated way. Unfortunately, while the following code:

```
map = leaflet(df) %>%
      addWebGLHeatmap(lng=~df$longitude, lat=~df$latitude, opacity= 1 , intensity = .5 ,size = 1000, gradientTexture='deep-sea', data=df)%>%
      addTiles(urlTemplate = map, attribution=attr)
```

Produces the desired image:

[image]

When I attempt to save the image in code (which I will eventually need to do) with the following code:

```
saveWidget(map, "tmp.html", selfcontained = F)
webshot("temp.html", file = "new_orleans.png", cliprect = "viewport")
```

I'm left with the following image instead:

[image]

I opened up an issue on the webshot github page, whose owner gave me this [response](https://github.com/wch/webshot/issues/67). I also know a similar issue was addressed on SO [last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460035/why-does-mapshot-in-r-mapview-package-not-save-the-addwebglheatmap-leaflet-ex), but there did not seem to be any resolution to it.

Since I have only seen examples of saving leaflet.extras maps with either webshot or mapshot (which gives me the exact same issue), I was wondering if anyone who has encountered this issue has been successful in resolving it through some sort of workaround, or with another R package that I am yet unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, with a call to `system` but I think that you can make this work with [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium) and your screenshot software that comes with your OS:

```
library(leaflet.extras)
library(leaflet)
library(RSelenium)

## addWebGLHeatmap
leaflet(quakes) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
  addWebGLHeatmap(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, size = 60000)

quakeplot <- leaflet(quakes) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
  addWebGLHeatmap(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, size = 60000)
quakeplot

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(quakeplot, "quake.html")

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox")
remDr <- rD$client

remDr$navigate(paste0("file://", getwd(), "/quake.html"))

Sys.sleep(5)
system("gnome-screenshot -f test2.png")
remDr$close()
```

I saved the file to my current working directory then used the `getwd()` to show that file in my browser. The `Sys.sleep()` call is because it seemed like the leaflet tiles took forever to load (which might be part of your original issue).

Final result:

[image]

Not perfect but still pretty good!

Comment: Thank you, this works great! A quick question, is there a way to get the program to either save the output of remDr$navigate(paste0("file://", getwd(), "/quake.html")) directly to a file? (saveWidget doesn't actually produce the heatmap, but the remDr$navigate command does) Or, alternatively, is there a different way of taking an image of the output that doesn't require me to toggle to a new window? Eventually I will want to automate this on a larger level and simply save the image to a file without having to do anything manually

Comment: Perhaps, RSelenum is merely an R client for [Selenium](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/) and using that might be better for customizing the browser pane and outputs a bit better.

Comment: I discovered that RSelenium has a screenshot option. So with remDr$screenshot(file='filename.png') you can get it to just capture the image in the browser window and save it to a file!